# How to reduce the number of nodes in a traced map using inkscape?

Tags: inkscape, image-trace, maps

I was trying to incorporate a map outline in a logo using trace bitmap feature in inkscape. I was able to trace with some modifications in the setting, but the problem is it has more number of nodes. I am trying to reduce the number of nodes using simplify command, but as soon as I do this I am loosing the curves of the map & even getting variable thickness. Is there any workaround to solve this problem. Also is there any other method to include maps in a logo without tracing?

This is the image what I achieved after tracing.[image: 1]

The same image after using path- simplify.
[image: m2]

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I would do the following:

1. Open the bitmap with a raster graphics editor like GIMP.
2. Use a paint bucket tool to fill in the areas so you have solid black shapes, instead of outlines. Clean up any rough edges or gaps in your fill.
3. **Use Inkscape to trace the *filled in* version** you just produced, and then delete the bitmap.
4. Style the resulting path with a stroke and no fill. Adjust the stroke width to taste.
5. Simplify the path. Use "Path" > "Simplfy", or edit manually with node tool and delete nodes as needed.
6. The resulting path may be slightly bloated since the path will lie along the outer edge of the thickness of the original path. Try fixing this first with a dynamic offset to bring it in a hair. If that doesn't produce satisfactory results, then you could: duplicate, set path thickness to double your desired thickness on the duplicate, convert stroke to path on duplicate, set no stroke and some fill on original, and then intersect the two (No adjusting the stroke width after this though).